# URLs: Files and Directories with the same name?

Tags: url, seo, directory, pagination, web-crawler

In an URL scheme, is it in any way disadvantageous if a directory and a file have the same name?

**I provide an example to illustrate what I mean:**

Let's say you want to do pagination. You could do it like this:

```
http://example.com/watches/page1
http://example.com/watches/page2
http://example.com/watches/page3
http://example.com/watches/page4
```

You could interpret that as: *There is a directory 'watches' which has 4 files – 'page1' to 'page4'.*

Now, the first page is probably going to be accessed quite often, so it makes sense to shorten the link to it:

```
http://example.com/watches
http://example.com/watches/page2
http://example.com/watches/page3
http://example.com/watches/page4
```

The first link will still show page 1, but the 'page1' is left off. And it will NOT redirect to

```
http://example.com/watches/page1
```

as that would force another round trip to the server.

You could interpret that as: *There is a **file** named 'watches' (which shows the first page in the category watches), **and** there is a **directory** 'watches' which has 3 files – 'page2' to 'page4'.*

**Here is my question again:** Is it in any way disadvantageous if a directory and a file have the same name, like 'watches' in the above example?

**Here are my thoughts on it:**

In terms of SEO, it probably is not disadvantageous, as AFAIK search engines have no notion of directories and thus treat URLs as blobs of characters. And as long as the URLs are different – which they are in my example – the search engine does not bother.

In case someone wants to archive my website with a web crawler like *wget* and mirror its contents on a local HDD, it could be a problem, as most file systems don't allow more than one file/directory to have the same name. However, IMHO this could easily be solved, e.g. by using *wget's* -E option, which adds the .html extension to HTML files, but not to directories.

Other than that, I see no problems. Do you?

Comment: In what filesystem can a file and directory have the same name? In any case -- in a URI there are no files/directories, only resources. As pointed out, any extra meaning has to be added. (Leaving me confused at the entire question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

By and large nowadays web servers do not read URI's as a directories and files, but as an address for a resource, and in many if not the majority of cases, the routing between the URI and the resource is complex.  This question as an example is not an HTML file in a directory.  Also web crawlers don't as a consequence have to cope with structures that don't work as filenames either.

I'm not sure quite what your issue is, but I hope this helps.